# Problem Retrieving Nextval in JPA Application

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need have a need to return nextVal at various times in my application. I have an entity class like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CACL")
public class Cacl {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "caclGenerator", sequenceName = "caclSeq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "calcGenerator")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Integer id;

// more stuff below....
```

, and I added the following in my repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface CaclRepository extends JpaRepository<Cacl, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT caclSeq.nextval FROM Cacl", nativeQuery = true)
Long getNextSeriesId();
```

However when I attempt to read it like this:

```
long nextval = caclRepository.getNextSeriesId() + 1;
```

, I get this exception:

(can't show entire stack trace)

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet


Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "cacl" does not exist
```

Its puzzling to me that I am getting error "cacl does not exist" because this application has been up and working for some time. All that I have done is add the @SequenceGenerator, updated the @GeneratorValue to link to the @SequenceGenerator annotation,  and create the new query. I would be grateful for any ideas as to what I am doing wrong. thanks

Comment: Do you have a sequence exists with `caclSeq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on simplifying my approach some. Now I am simply using the default sequences supplied by postgress. So for instance now I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_CACL")
public class Cacl {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

// more stuff below...
```

, then in the repository (after querying postgress to get default sequences) I have:

```
@Query(value = "select last_value from tbl_cacl_id_seq", nativeQuery = true)
    public Integer getCurrentVal();
```

And then:

```
int nextval = caclRepository.getCurrentVal();
```

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you could try removing the native query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT nextval('caclSeq')", nativeQuery =
        true)
Long getNextSeriesId();
```

Comment: Seabastion, thanks but that will not compile: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [caclSeq.nextval], unexpected token [caclSeq] [SELECT caclSeq.nextval FROM fbi.prometheus.aps.clients.caclclient.model.Cacl]
"

Comment: and if you try the dual? update the answer

Comment: Sebastion, compiles but throws following exception when calling method: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist
  Position: 29

Comment: Hi update the answer because the dual is bd oracle in use postgres

Comment: Sebastian, that throws the original exception I got above: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "caclseq" does not exist